# Why doesn't this git alias to find remote branches work?

Tags: git, batch-file, alias, command-prompt, git-alias

I'm on Windows Command Prompt (don't judge).

I have this command:

```
git remote show origin | grep \w*\s*(new^|tracked) -E
```

This works fine, printing what I expect:

```
    dev                                  tracked
    master                               tracked
    my-account                           tracked
    payment-request                      tracked
```

I've tried to add it as an alias:

```
git config --global alias.branches "!git remote show origin | grep \w*\s*(new^|tracked) -E"
```

My config file looks like this:

```
alias.branches=!git remote show origin | grep \w*\s*(new^|tracked) -E
```

But when I run it:

```
>git branches

git remote show origin | grep \w*\s*(new^|tracked) -E: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
git remote show origin | grep \w*\s*(new^|tracked) -E: -c: line 0: `git remote show origin | grep \w*\s*(new^|tracked) -E'
```

I don't understand why this is giving this syntax error here, when it worked perfectly fine when I manually ran the command. Why is this error occurring, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try with

```
git remote show origin | grep \w*\s*'(new^|tracked)' -E
```

in your alias, on linux I have the same error when I run your command and it works when I add the '

Comment: Thank you! This works. I guess git aliases are being run on Bash or something? Also, to add this as an alias, you'd do `git config --global alias.branches "!git remote show origin | grep \w*\s*'(new^|tracked)' -E`

Comment: right, I am not sure how it is done for windows but for *nix users like, you would update the .gitconfig file directly and update the [alias] section

Comment: Git has built in support to directly add an alias: `git config --global alias.[name] "[alias]"` But yeah you can also manually edit the `.gitconfig` file.